# Documentum Registered Table object retrieval error

Tags: documentum

**Environment:** DA 7.3, D2 4.7, MS SQL Server 2012, Win Serv 2012 R2, Tomcat 8

- When executing this DQL Query:

> **SELECT * FROM dm_registered**

it retrieves all registered table instances found (nearly 32 instances) --> 3 of them i created using the command:

**REGISTER TABLE [ owner_name.] table_name ( column_def {,column_def}**

- when querying any registered table ***except***  the (3 i created) using the QDL Query, i receive a result, but when i query any of the (3 i created) using the DA Query Editor it outputs the following error:

  **Error occured during query execution :[DM_QUERY2_E_TABLE_NOT_FOUND]error: "The database table or view was not found in the database. Error from the database was: ' -- The database object is invalid -- STATE=42S02, CODE=208, MSG=[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dmadmin.employee'.**
- the same happens when i  open D2 and navigate to registered tables menu i could select from the menu the registered tables, i found the (3 created registered table objects) but when select any of them i found the same error that i got with DA DQL Editor.

[image]

[image: D2 registered table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that the table was not created in the database, i don't know how i missed that critical step.

> Simply the answer is

- Create the table in the database identical to the registered table.

now i am able to query the table using the DQL query (no need for alias)

**SELECT * FROM dm_dbo.employee**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to put alias in front:
SELECT * FROM dm_dbo.employee

Comment: Actually i missed an important step that caused the error, which is (I have not created the table) that's the reason.